# New Div Created WIth Ajax Call and Image/Link Click Gets Disabled

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've an image uploader in a project and uploading images with Ajax that works perfect. It shows uploaded images instantly without page refresh. Here is the code that I am using to upload images:

```
<script>
$(function () {
            $('#btnUpload').click(function () {
                var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);

                var files = fileUpload.files;
                var test = new FormData();
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    test.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../UI/Upload.ashx",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: test,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                        //This section refreshes the div with uploaded images and shows images without full page refresh
                        $('#divImages').load(document.URL + ' #divImages');
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>


<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />
<input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Files" />

 <div id="divImages" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="labelImages" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

The problem is after uploading images, the images are shown in the content but unable to click the images and a '**Delete**' link is associated with every image that also seems to be blocked. Then when I refresh the full page, the click on the images and links works. I am not sure why it happens? In the inspect element of the browser, I can see newly div created inside like the below:

```
 <div id="divImages"> //The newly created div after partial refresh with Ajax every time I upload image
   <div id="divImages" clientidmode="Static" runat="server">
     <asp:Label ID="labelImages" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Does it prevent me to click on the images/buttons or anything else? Would be grateful if it is pointed out.

This is the code I am using for deleting images with links (Basically I am using the links as button):

```
 $('#divImages a.deleteLink').click(function () { //Ajax used to delete images from 'Images' folder with jQuery

            var image = $(this).attr("img");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../UI/DeleteImage.ashx",
                data: "imageName=" + image,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == "true") {
                        $('#divImages a.imageLink[imgsrc*=\"' + image + '\"]').fadeOut();
                        $('#divImages a.deleteLink[img=\"' + image + '\"]').fadeOut();
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('There was an error. ' + response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is the code for your button clicks? Is this in jquery or pure asp?

Comment: I am using C# to bind dynamic controls from code-behind and doing the button click (Basically HyperLinks are used as Buttons) with Ajax at front-end. I've posted the code for the deletion. This section gets disabled after Ajax partial refresh.

Comment: use jquery `on` to catch events from dynamically created elements so instead of `$('#divImages A.deleteLink').click(function () { ` change it to `$('#divImages A.deleteLink').on('click', function () {`

Comment: Tried the above. Still it does not delete. I've to refresh the whole page to make it work.

Comment: try this : `$('body').on('click', '#divImages a.deleteLink', function() {` I wonder why you are using `A` than `a`

Comment: Hey Desperado! Yes, it worked like a charm. Post it as an answer and let me mark as an answer. By the way, what is the difference between the declaration you made in jQuery specifically the last one.

Comment: thanks! always remember that dynamically created elements have a different behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asked me to post this as an answer and I can't do anything about it.

See my explanation in the comments section

```
$('body').on('click', '#divImages a.deleteLink', function() {
```